# Using Autocomplete on Second Level Page in ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I know this is probably something really easy.

I'm trying to use an autocomplete function to fill in a field when a user registers. I've tried the script on an index page for the controller (such as ~/home or ~/Account). But when I go down a level to Account/Register, how do I include the script in my Return View?

**Account Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using AccountModule_Attempt_5.Filters;
using AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register

        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        public ActionResult autocomplete(string term)
        {

      var model =
                db.Customers
                .Where(r => r.No_.StartsWith(term))
                //.Take(10)

                .Select(r => new
                {
                    label = r.No_
                });
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
       {

            return View();
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

  //  autocomplete
    var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.val(ui.item.label);

        var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
        $form.submit();
    }


    var createAutocomplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
            select: submitAutocompleteForm,
        };

        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };

    $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
});
```

**View**

```
@model AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>

          <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer_No_)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_No_, new { data_otf_autocomplete = Url.Action("Autocomplete")})
            </li>
        </ol>
}
```

**_layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customer", "Index", "Customer")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Profile", "Index", "UserProfile")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "Index", "Roles")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otf").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
             "~/Scripts/otf.js"
            ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that the script actually is working in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I can't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel dumb. It was a simple typo. I had @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base") instead of @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base")

Answer (score 0):

if you layout page and include your styles and scripts there like below

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

<!-- Global stylesheets -->
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<!-- /global stylesheets -->
<!-- Core JS files -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<!-- /core JS files -->
<!-- Theme JS files -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Theme")
<!-- /theme JS files -->

</head>
```

and when your actionresult view use this layout all of your scripts work there.
your view code like this

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do have these scripts in a bundle in my _layout.cshtml. The script is working. My question is how do I return a view and a json in the same view? I've added my _layout and Bundle for reference.

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery Autocomplete](https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin) for example

```
function EnableSearchAutocomplete(url, img) {
var formatItem = function (row) {
    if (!row) return "";
    return "<img src='" + img + "' /> " + row[0];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#term").autocomplete(url, {
        dir: 'rtl', minChars: 2, delay: 5,
        mustMatch: false, max: 20, autoFill: false,
        matchContains: false, scroll: false, width: 300,
        formatItem: formatItem
    }).result(function (evt, row, formatted) {
        if (!row) return;
        window.location = row[1];
    });
  });
}
```

on your view side

```
@{

var scoredTermsUrl = Url.Action(actionName: "ScoredTerms", controllerName: "Home");
var bulletImage = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/bullet_shape.png");
```

}

### View

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        EnableSearchAutocomplete('@scoredTermsUrl', '@bulletImage');
    </script>
}
```

then your Controller

```
public virtual ActionResult ScoredTerms(string q)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q))
            return Content(string.Empty);

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var items = AutoComplete.GetTermsScored(_indexPath, q);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var postUrl = this.Url.Action(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Home", routeValues: new { id = item.Id }, protocol: "http");
            result.AppendLine(item.Title + "|" + postUrl);
        }

        return Content(result.ToString());
    }
```